# When exactly does tvOS purge data?

Tags: tvos

I am planning to use Core Data to store downloaded data (about 2mb in all). Apple's docs state:

"Your app can download the data it needs into its cache directory. Downloaded data is not deleted while the app is running. However, when space is low and your app is not running, this data may be deleted. Do not use the entire cache space as this can cause unpredictable results."

Does this mean the data can be purged when the app is in the background or only when it is really quit (by sliding the app up in the "running app Cover-Flow-Like view")?

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in CoreData is different from the app's cache directory and is not subject to being deleted by tvOS.